# What's the highest you can upgrade the Enhanced Dwarven Crossbow to?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have got the Enhanced Dwarven Crossbow in Skyrim and I have upgraded it to Superior and it keeps saying when trying to upgrade it again "You do not have the level needed"

Can you go higher than Superior?

Answer (score 2):

Have you put a perk point into Dwarven Smithing?  If not superior is all you'd be able to get.

Also if its magical, you have to put a perk point into Arcane Smithing to improve magic items.  I doubt this is your issue, since you said you got it to superior.

See this [Skyrim Blacksmithing youtube video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSAQ2FM7jK8) for the blacksmith list.

- Dwarven is at 0:44 in video.
- Arcane is at 1:12 in video.

PS I have no idea the quality of the video, I just used it as a reference.

Comment: Yes i could only put 1 on (like normal) I guess i can only get it to superior and it does have "Ignores 50% of armor" not sure if it does still count as magic. I don't have the patience to get my smithing really high (especially when i can level by stealing stuff :P)

Comment: I 'improve' all my stolen items - easiest way to increase smithing...  Enchanting stolen weapons after that, iron daggers, steel daggers are the best with absorb health turns a 10gp item into a 200-400gp item.  A bow with soul trap of 1 second is good for getting lots of charged soul gems.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to improve your smithing to improve items better. That's sort of the point.

Answer (score 0):

Items can be upgraded to legendary status. I have legendary Daedric and Dragon-Plated armour. I believe it is only possible to Make legendary stuff when you've reached 100 in smithing; Which is really easy and only takes about 10 minutes. Just buy some materials to make an Iron dagger, make several, Sell them, use that money to buy more supplies, repeat. Takes no time at all.

Comment: it takes about 2-4 hours to max your smithing for me.

Comment: i think you are understating the fact that you need money and the merchant is not endless in its materials. so yeah i think 10 minutes is exaggerating it..

Comment: If you save, attack merchant and load, he will reset.